# How to check which port to enable on Windows Server 2008 Firewall

Tags: windows, networking, sql-server, port, windows-firewall

I have an application which supposed to be launch from a client machine, but every time I launch it, it shows me an error saying **"Failed to talk to database"**.

By the way it is a .Net application and database is SQLExpress2008R2. The app itself is stored in the app server (windows Server 2008). When I launch the app from the server, it works. But when I do it from the client machine, it showed me the error.

I managed to fix the problem by disabling the Windows Firewall (for Public) on the App Server.
When it's disabled, everything works fine but obviously my client doesn't like that option. So how am I going to allow the application to bypass the windows server 2008 firewall?

I have done all sort of things like adding rules for port 1433, set TCP/IP on for SQLExpress and disable the dynamic port etc, that all didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check that the socket your SQL server is listening on is really 0.0.0.0:1433 by using `netstat -an`. If not, check the network configuration for the SQL server. If it does, check if your inbound rule allowing traffic to 1433/tcp is correctly defined and enabled. This should cover the two most probable causes.